# PhaseScriptExecution when run react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Why I always get this error when i try to build react native apps in ios:

> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/azam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYApp-dxzjsftrfjgxmpbvucqtgzeybiwr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MYApp.build/QA.debug-iphonesimulator/MYApp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'MYApp' from project 'MYApp')
> (1 failure)

I tried cleaning node_modules, yarn.lock, remove Pods and podfile.lock folder, reinstall yarn and pod install but no luck at all, I even removed the DerivedData folder and everytime i tried to build, will get the same error, any solid solution for me?

this happens on

- "react-native": "^0.70.13"
- "react": "18.2.0"
- MacBook Pro Intel Core i5
- macOS 13.3 (22E245) SDK (Built-in)
- iOS 16.4 (20E238) SDK + iOS 16.4 (20E247) Simulator (Built-in)